# Is there a standard Haskell function that prepends an extra parameter to a function

Tags: haskell

I have a function `a->b` which is to be passed to something of `(c->a->b)` signature. I don't care about `c` will just ignore it. Is there a standard function that prepends useless parameters: `(a->b) -> (c->a->b)` ?

Comment: [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+c+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+b%29) can also be helpful for questions like this, although it does really poorly in this case

Comment: tried this exact signature, didn't find anything

Comment: that's what I meant by "it does really poorly in this case", sorry. I think hoogle should be trying to capture common terms and return the most general functions satisfying those types first, but it doesn't seem to do that

Answer (score 12):

It's called [`const`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:const):

```
> let foo = const :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a -> b)
```